# MVC3 Razor View Optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there any better way as compared to **@if @else** Just to changes few attributes (like disabled, value, class etc) of html element in cshtml page built with Razor view?

Comment: Well i'don't know how to avoid usinf "if/else". Maybe short if/else syntax will help you @(true ? "enabled" : "disabled"). Other way you can create helper or count attribute values in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC 4/Razor V2 will have some improvements:

**Conditional attribute rendering**

If you have an attribute that might be null, in the past you've needed to do a null check to avoid writing out an empty attribute, like this:

```
<div @{if (myClass != null) { <text>class="@myClass"</text> } }>Content</div>
```

Now Razor is able to handle that automatically, so you can just write out the attribute. If it's null, the attribute isn't written:

```
<div class="@myClass">Content</div>
```

So if `@myClass` is `null`, the output is just this:

```
<div>Content</div>
```

From [Jon Galloway's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/02/16/asp-net-4-beta-released.aspx).

Comment: that would be amazing feature..like it :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use inline conditional statements as well:

```
<input type="text" value="@(true == true ? "one value" : "another value")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think there is any performance flaw with razor `@if` but you can use Your `ViewModel` or `ViewBag` for this:

```
<input type="text" value="@(ViewBag.TheValue)" />
```

But for best practice, Don't mix server side logic with the presentation. *"Separate of concerns"*

---

**Update**(What did I mean by *"separate of concerns"*):

It mean the View should contains as much as it can, HTML markups and HTML helpers(which just help you write markup) only. Don't put logic inside the View. don't reuse the same view if it makes you put code inside of it.

Comment: I want to tidy up the code..I need to use multiple and nested if else statements which has generated conflicts in 'ID' of elements as well..

Comment: @user1270199. Show some **real** code. It looks like you're using razor the wrong way!

Comment: when u say "Don't mix server side logic with the presentation" does it means use Viewbag.Value for all the dynamic attributes?

Comment: @user1270199. No, It mean the View should contains as much as it can, HTML markups and HTML helpers(which just help you write markup) only. Don't put logic inside the View. don't reuse the same view if it makes you put code inside the view.

Comment: Oh, got it. In your example if 'value' attribute needs to conditional as well then any way to do it??

Comment: @Amyz. `<input type="text" @(ViewBag.Value)" />` And in the controller `ViewBag.Value = "value=theValue"`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them in the ViewModel as true/false values or string values.
For example -

- anything that needs to be dynamically set to be enabled or disabled - you can create a bool
- any html class that is a string set on runtime, can be passed as a string variable in your view model.

etc.

That would clean up your razor views of all the @if else statements

Comment: hmm sounds like interesting- html.helpers could be more interesting (I have seen in google ;))

Comment: i am not sure how you are planning to use html helpers for this purpose

Comment: like using MvcHtmlString StatusClass to select a perticular class based on condition..I am not handy in MvcHtmlString extention methodes though :(